# Why are chemistry droppers bad at holding bromine?

Tags: density

Question in my chemistry test last week. The question was related to a previous question on bromine's density.

Comment: I imagine it has much more to do with bromine's vapor pressure (which is high). Pipettes have trouble with diethyl ether and other high vapor pressure liquids as well.

Comment: The diameter of the orifice of a "standard" dropper is "sized" to work well with water. But bromine has three factors that work against that large size. (1) Density of liquid (2) lower surface tension and (3) high vapor pressure.

Comment: Bromine seems not to wet glass which would be another reason that a dropper doesn't work well.  https://books.google.com/books?id=cm46AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=bromine+%22wet%22+glass?&source=bl&ots=a7orFKoQ_q&sig=IEGZvJC4UqqJMmpBjbkheA9B-eM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMg9TNpMjJAhVEdj4KHVQSBbYQ6AEIQDAH#v=onepage&q=bromine%20%22wet%22%20glass%3F&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Since the standard dropper is designed to hold common liquid such as water or ethanol, the capillary size have some particular size. When it comes to bromine, the density is 3 times of water. In other words, the dropper need to hold a super heavy droplet, so you could expect that it won't be as efficient as usual. In addition, your previous question hinted on the density, so it is pretty obvious right?